# Creating new Elsa 3.0 client API key - Issues following documentation

Tags: elsa-workflows

I am new to Elsa and trying to follow documentation here under https://v3.elsaworkflows.io/docs/installation/aspnet-apps-workflow-server - Users and applications section to create a new API key rather than use admin user and Api key. This documentation suggests to remove the lines
identity.UseAdminUserProvider();
identity.TokenOptions = options => options.SigningKey = "secret-token-signing-key";
but I get unauthorized without it. I used           identity.UseAdminUserProvider();
and the below code to overcome that error. I am getting a client API key but using that I am running into unauthorized at the step "send the following request to the /identity/users endpoint using the API key we just created:"
elsa.UseIdentity(identity =>
{

```
     var configuration = builder.Configuration;
     var identitySection = configuration.GetSection("Identity");
     var identityTokenSection = identitySection.GetSection("Tokens");

     identity.IdentityOptions = options => identitySection.Bind(options);
     identity.TokenOptions = options => identityTokenSection.Bind(options);
     identity.UseConfigurationBasedUserProvider(options => identitySection.Bind(options));
     identity.UseConfigurationBasedApplicationProvider(options => identitySection.Bind(options));
     identity.UseConfigurationBasedRoleProvider(options => identitySection.Bind(options));

     identity.UseAdminUserProvider();
 });
```

I am following the documentation strictly. Can someone help with rectifying documentation/what I might be doing wrong.

2. The nuget package for the same article https://v3.elsaworkflows.io/docs/installation/aspnet-apps-workflow-server seems to be in error for Elsa 3.0
   using Elsa.Http.Extensions;
   using Elsa.Identity.Extensions;
3. I am not able to see console output in visual studio. Can someone provide detailed instructions how I can see that in visual studio.

Answer (score 1):

```cs
elsa.UseDefaultAuthentication(auth => auth.UseAdminApiKey());
```

Changing the above code to the following fixed it for me:

```cs
elsa.UseDefaultAuthentication();
```